# incorrect work methods bindServer() when trying to connect to the service, after the application is restarted

Tags: android, android-service

Today, working with the Service for Android, has faced some "illogical" or "not correctly", in my opinion, the work method `bindService`. The essence of the confusion that I created in the application service that is within you, with the `ExecutorService` makes a request. When I went to the application, the service remained alive - the queries are executed in separate threads with a certain cyclical (logs confirm this). In the method onStart() I have written code that, by all manuals and tutorials should give me access to the service, that I have run before, with this application. But all our advise it seemed evident. I expected that calling `bindService()` -> I get a connection to a running service. But no, instead, at the first attempt the connection is not happening - I do not understand why. I added code that would run the service itself, if it has not been done before. So this part of the code is activated and again I try to connect to just running the service. And yes, the connection is successful, but - connection nourish my service I was expecting to get from the first connection attempt. And judging from the logs of my attempt to re-create the service does not lead to its creation. All this follows from the log. And in this regard, I wonder - why the first attempt to connect it does not happen? Or am I doing wrong?

**fragment code in Activity**

```
...
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            flagServiceConnection = true;
            Log.d("StartActivity/serviceConnection", "serviceConnection/onServiceConnected() -> connected");
            exService = ((ExService.ExBinder) service).getService();
            exService.setFlagBroadcast(true);
            exService.getAll();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            flagServiceConnection = false;
            Log.d("StartActivity/serviceConnection", "serviceConnection/onServiceDisconnected() -> disconnected");
        }       
    };
...
public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();        
        bindService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ExService.class), serviceConnection, 0);       
        if(!flagServiceConnection){
            Log.d("StartActivity", "onStart() -> start service");
            this.startService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ExService.class));
            bindService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ExService.class), serviceConnection, 0);           
        }       
    }
```

**Log**

```
D/StartActivity(5922): onCreate()
D/StartActivity(5922): onStart() -> start service
D/StartActivity/serviceConnection(5922): erviceConnection/onServiceConnected() -> connected
D/-(5922): pront.android.exservice.ExService$Monitor@4056b4c8
D/-(5922): pront.android.exservice.ExService$Monitor@405480e0
D/-(5922): pront.android.exservice.ExService$Monitor@4054ee18
D/ExService(5922): onRebind()
D/ExService(5922): onStartCommand() -> service start
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first connection attempt works, but your `flagServiceConnection` check doesn't, so you **always** try to connect one more time, and here's why.

When you call `bindService()` method, you are not connected to the service immediately, so your `flagServiceConnection` is not set yet when you try to check it.

I assume the purpose of your check is to start service before binding if it is not started yet. To achieve this, you need to call `bindService()` with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();        
    bindService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ExService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);       
    //that's it, if service is not started, it will be started automatically 
    //no need for additional checks         
    }       
}
```

Comment: no no no - I know about the possibility of service to start automatically, but I am wondering why the first connection attempt was not successful?

Comment: you are not bound to the service immediately when you call `bindService()` method. You check for `flagServiceConnection` in your next statement (executed immediately), but this flag is set only when service is connected (in `onServiceConnected()`). Try setting default value of `flagServiceConnection` to `true` to understand my point :)

Comment: I checked back the other way - yes indeed, the connection to the service is not immediate - here I had a simple test - an average Connections lasts 50 milliseconds. Thanks for the tip.